# Pyomo Abstract model for Machine learning model output constraints in optimization

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, tree, pyomo

I am working on an optimization problem using the Abstract model in Pyomo. The objective function is a linear function of decision variables whose coefficients come from the ‘values.dat’ file. The constraints are upper and lower bounds on the value of output variables where decision variables along with a list of user inputs go as an input to a trained machine learning model (multiple input multiple output regression) stored in variable ‘estimator’. The upper and lower bounds on the value of output variables come from the dataframe ‘out_range’ created using training data.

In the case where distance based regression techniques such as Linear regression, Ridge, Lasso, etc. are used to train a machine learning model stored in ‘estimator’, the optimizer runs successfully giving values of decision variables.

But in the case where tree-based regression techniques such as KNN, Random Forest, etc. are used to train a machine learning model stored in ‘estimator’, the optimizer throws the error given below.

Code block for the optimization:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd
import joblib

filename = 'model_Ridge.pkl'       # use model pickle files 'model_Ridge or model_Decision Tree'
estimator = joblib.load(filename)


x_inp = [0.8101265822784809,
        0.802431611347517,
        1.145142857599998,
        0.5823611752600839,
        0.7556756748240172,
        0.37747819179144226,
        0.6501687291338578,
        0.3826800178066474,
         0.7857142833333342,
         0.30769230821005866,
         0.4729729730277574,
         0.1079607425922493,
         0.2260967374953724,
         -0.08108108128560954,
         0.5316094312055879,
         0.12634964888607925,
         -0.3808357060152776]

boundcsv_file = '...\\Output_range.csv'
out_range = pd.read_csv(boundcsv_file, header=0)

boundcsv_file = '...\\Input_ratio_range.csv'
inp_range = pd.read_csv(boundcsv_file, header=0)

n_p = 6

model = AbstractModel()
model.m = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.n = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.I = RangeSet(1, model.m)
model.J = RangeSet(1, model.n)
model.p = Param(model.I)
model.r = Var(model.I,domain=Reals)

#Objective function
def obj_expression(model):
    return summation(model.p, model.r)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

# Lower bound constraint on output variables 
def low_constraint_rule(m,j):
    a = []
    #Creating a list out of decision variables
    for d in range(1,n_p+1):
        a.append(m.r[d])
    #Concatenating the list of user input 'x_inp' and decision variables to pass to machine learning model

    #Checking each output variables value with bound value
    return (estimator.predict([x_inp + a])[0,j-1] >= out_range.iat[0,j-1])

# Upper bound constraint on output variables 
def high_constraint_rule(m,j):
    a = [] 
    for d in range(1,n_p+1):
        a.append(m.r[d])          
    return (estimator.predict([x_inp+a])[0,j-1] <= out_range.iat[1,j-1])

def equal_constraint_rule(m):        
    return (summation(m.r) == 1)

def low_dv_constraint_rule(m,i):          
    return (m.r[i] >= inp_range.iat[0,i-1])

def high_dv_constraint_rule(m,i):          
    return (m.r[i] <= inp_range.iat[1,i-1])


model.AxbConstraint_l = Constraint(model.J, rule = low_constraint_rule)
model.AxbConstraint_h = Constraint(model.J, rule = high_constraint_rule)
model.AxbConstraint_dv = Constraint(rule = equal_constraint_rule)
model.AxbConstraint_dv_l = Constraint(model.I, rule = low_dv_constraint_rule)
model.AxbConstraint_dv_h = Constraint(model.I, rule = high_dv_constraint_rule)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename = 'values.dat', model=model)
instance = model.create_instance(data)
solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = solver.solve(instance)
instance.display()
print(results)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (r[1]) to         
float is disabled.
This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as      arguments to
one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining
expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions or
explicitly resolving the numeric value using the Pyomo value() function.

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint  AxbConstraint_l
with index 1: TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (r[1])
to float is disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo
components as arguments to one of the Python built-in math module
functions when defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-
provided math functions or explicitly resolving the numeric value using
the Pyomo value() function.
ERROR: Constructing component 'AxbConstraint_l' from data=None failed:
TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (r[1]) to float
is disabled.
This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to
one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining
expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions or
explicitly resolving the numeric value using the Pyomo value() function.
```

Comment: You should edit your post and post the actual code **not** a screenshot.  Also include any data needed to make the model run and reproduce the error.  If you have a data frame, I'd suggest chopping it down to a minimal example that generates the error and posting the data frame as a table or dictionary or such.

Comment: You cannot use arbitrary functions like `estimator.predict` as part of the model.  Without seeing exactly what that is, it is impossible to troubleshoot.